# Is there a DotNetNuke 6 Module Development Template for Visual Studio?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Can anybody tell me how to install a module development template for DotNeTNuke. Please note that I am working in DNN 6 and using Visual Studio 2010. So the template must be compatible with both DNN 6 and VS 2010. I have tried one that was for VS 2010 but not for DNN 6. Please suggest any links or videos.

Answer (score 3):

There is a development template that's released with every version of DotNetNuke, available in both the DotNetNuke Support Network (for paid edition customers), and in the [official downloads area](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Downloads.aspx) for the Community Edition.  Just click on the Visual Studio Starter Kit.

If you want a more complete visual studio template, I would highly recommend the templates that [Chris Hammond put together on Codeplex](http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/), that bdukes mentioned.  There are templates for both VB and C#, and they include automated packaging for your modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can get c# version of module development template from http://dnnmodule.codeplex.com/.

There are some minor changes in module development for each new major version of dnn changes, but there are no templates dedicated to the version of dnn till yet since we assume our module should work in any version starting from 4.x to 6.x.

Let me know if you want any other help.

Comment: You'll just want to update the DotNetNuke.dll that is distributed with that template to the 6 version.  You might also want to look at http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/, which has automated packaging built into it (its reference to DotNetNuke.dll just looks at the website's bin folder, so nothing to change there).